# Return 404 in Laravel RouteServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to give a 404 response if index.php is found in the url.
example url is `domain.com/index.php/about`

expected :
return blade 404

I've tried this code but can't get the 404 display

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    public function map()
    {
        $this->removeIndexPhpFromUrl();
    }

    protected function removeIndexPhpFromUrl()
    {
        $currentUrl = url()->current();
        if(strpos($currentUrl, 'index.php') !== false){
            return view('errors.404');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using middleware will be a perfect solution  https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: go through the laravel docs for middleware https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code for solving this problem

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Foundation\Support\Collectable;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }


    public function map()
    {
        $this->removeIndexPhpFromUrl();
    }

    protected function removeIndexPhpFromUrl()
    {
        $currentUrl = url()->current();
        if(strpos($currentUrl, 'index.php') !== false){
            $url = str_replace('/index.php','', $currentUrl);
            return redirect()->to($url)->send();
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't use `abort(404)` in this RouteServiceProvider.php